# How to run controller_manager

Tags: ros, rosservice, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I use a launch file to load a controller:

```
 <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" args="controller/twist"/>
```

When I run the launch file, the system said waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller.

But when I type `rosservice call controller_manager/load_controller` it told me that service is not available.

Do I need to run controller_manager first before calling that service? If yes, how I run controller_manager?

Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199042/how-to-run-controller_manager/) by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-12-07

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `spawner` script is one of the command-line tools offered by the controller_manager ROS package ([doc](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager#spawner)), and it does *not* start a `controller_manager` instance.

The `controller_manager`is typically instantiated inside your robot hardware abstraction (`hardware_interface::RobotHW` specialization). If using `gazebo_ros_control`, this is already done by the existing plugins ([Tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control)), but if using on a custom abstraction, you have to do the setup yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2014-12-09**:
Can you take a look at http://answers.ros.org/question/198929/running-controller_manager-spawner-with-mybotrobot_description/?

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-12-10**:
Can you reproduce the results of this tutorial? http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_control
If in indigo, you'll have to specify the `<hardware_interface>` element as a child of `<joint>`, not `<actuator>`, in your URDF transmissions.